# Subscribe to External Azure Web PubSub Service from Azure

Tags: azure, websocket, client, publish-subscribe, subscriber

I have an external vendor who would like me to subscribe to their Azure Web PubSub service from which I will receive notifications when a certain event occurs.  What is the best way to subscribe to these events from my own Azure environment?   I am familiar with handling HTTP requests from Azure Functions and Azure Logic Apps, but this is my first time using Websockets within Azure (and I am new to Azure itself).

Edit:  Also, I have read the documentation on Azure Web PubSub and have followed along with some of the tutorials.  Most either show how to subscribe from a C# console application or a web app, but what if I want to kick off a workflow in Azure when the notification is received?

Answer (score 1):

> subscribe to their Azure Web PubSub service from which I will receive notifications when a certain event occurs

Looks like you will be acting as the [event handler upstream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-web-pubsub/concept-service-internals#event-handler) role. You can have an app server running and listen to the CloudEvents HTTP request from Azure Web PubSub service. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-web-pubsub/reference-cloud-events

Here is a sample about handling events: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-web-pubsub/tutorial-build-chat?tabs=csharp#handle-events